# get direction with google maps api without using a map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

Hi I'm playing around with a frontend project which will have no backend and I want it to get transit direction from a specific place to another.

The problem I have is that google maps api for browser does always have to use a map if I'm correct.

I just want to show e.g 3 next bus from this bus stop.

It so much documentation on different things and I'm not sure which api to use. Could I use server api?

Any google api pro out there who could help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map is not required.  The [Google Maps Javascript API v3 DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) can just render the text directions in the "panel" (an HTML div).

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsRenderer):

> setPanel(panel:Node) | Return Value:  None
>   This method renders the directions in a . Pass null to remove the content from the panel.

**code snippet:** (modified from [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel))

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

  var onChangeHandler = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  };
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <strong>Start:</strong>
  <select id="start">
    <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
    <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
    <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
    <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
    <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
    <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
    <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
    <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
    <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
    <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
    <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
    <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <strong>End:</strong>
  <select id="end">
    <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
    <option value="st louis, mo" selected="selected">St Louis</option>
    <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
    <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
    <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
    <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
    <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
    <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
    <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
    <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
    <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
    <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="right-panel"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Do you know if I can get all busses that goes from a specific place. e.g Get 10 next busses going from a specific buss station to any direction.